# Github Actions dynamic container name

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, github-actions

### Summary:

Github Actions allows using Docker containers to run jobs, but it doesn't seem to allow providing a dynamic value for this container image (using environment variables).

This works (not the desired solution):

```yaml
jobs:
  pytest-test:
    container:
      image: ghcr.io/ashrafgt/test:latest    ...
```

This does not work (the desired solution):

```yaml
jobs:
  pytest-test:
    container:
      # env variables defined at the start of the workflow
      image: ${{ env.REGISTRY_NAME }}/test:${{ env.IMAGE_TAG }} 
    ...
```

Giving this error:

```sh
Invalid workflow file : .github/workflows/workflow.yaml
The workflow is not valid. Unrecognized named-value: 'env'. Located at position 1 within expression: env.REGISTRY_NAME
```

Are there any ways to do this besides doing a `run: docker run ...`?

### Full Example:

In this example, I try to build and push a Docker image (tagged with the current commit SHA) then use the same image to run unit tests:

```yaml
name: Main CI Pipeline

on: [push]

env:
  REGISTRY_NAME: ghcr.io/${{ github.repository_owner }}
  REGISTRY_USERNAME: ${{ github.actor }}
  REGISTRY_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
  IMAGE_TAG: ${{ github.sha }}

jobs:

  docker-build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1
      - uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          registry: ${{ env.REGISTRY_NAME }}
          username: ${{ env.REGISTRY_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ env.REGISTRY_PASSWORD }}
      - uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          tags: ${{ env.REGISTRY_NAME }}/test:${{ env.IMAGE_TAG }}
          push: true

  pytest-test:
    needs: docker-build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: read
    container:
      image: ${{ env.REGISTRY_NAME }}/test:${{ env.IMAGE_TAG }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: pytest
```

Please find the full repository [here](https://github.com/ashrafgt/github-actions-dynamic-container).

The full error message is:

```sh
Invalid workflow file : .github/workflows/workflow.yaml#L38
The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/workflow.yaml (Line: 38, Col: 14): Unrecognized named-value: 'env'. Located at position 1 within expression: env.REGISTRY_NAME
```

Please find the Github Actions run [here](https://github.com/ashrafgt/github-actions-dynamic-container/actions/runs/1569706674).

### Fix Attempts:

1. Using only `container` instead of `container.image`:

   ```yaml
   jobs:
     pytest-test:
       container: ${{ env.REGISTRY_NAME }}/test:${{ env.IMAGE_TAG }} 
       ...
   ```
2. Using the `docker://` syntax for a single step:

   ```yaml
   jobs:
     pytest-test:
       steps:
         - uses: docker://${{ env.REGISTRY_NAME }}/test:${{ env.IMAGE_TAG }}
           entrypoint: pytest
       ...
   ```

Both fix attempts failed with the same error as the original syntax.

Comment: Not sure if this is outdated already, but the topic seems to be a bit inconsistent.

But according to this:
https://github.community/t/how-to-use-env-context/16975/2

"You cannot use env context in the value of a workflow environment variable. But you can use it in jobs.<job_id>.steps.env."

You could also try: https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/issues/68#issuecomment-792338408

Comment: I tried to follow the answers in both articles you shared, essentially trying like this: https://github.com/ashrafgt/github-actions-dynamic-container/blob/578cdcc6004f8f8175ea7a7993e22a8bfe309edb/.github/workflows/workflow.yaml#L38

The YAML variable expansion doesn't seem to work outside a `run` attribute (I need the expansion in the `container.image` attribute).

Answer (score 2):

`env` context is not available for `container` or `container.image`. Following is a snapshot from the GitHub Actions plugin on VSCode where the linter throws an error.

[image: dynamic-containers]

Alternatively, you can define [configuration variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#defining-configuration-variables-for-multiple-workflows) in GitHub at a repo/org level and then use the `vars` context to access it ([example](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#using-the-vars-context-to-access-configuration-variable-values))

Answer (score 1):

I was also surprised to see that this does not work.
However, I stumbled across this blogpost: https://aschmelyun.com/blog/using-docker-run-inside-of-github-actions/

It uses a [predefined github action](https://github.com/addnab/docker-run-action) to access `docker run`.
So you could edit your file to look like this instead:

```yaml
    pytest-test:
        needs: docker-build
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
          - name: Check out the repo
            uses: actions/checkout@v2
          - name: Run Pytest inside Docker
            uses: addnab/docker-run-action@v3
            with:
                image: ${{ env.REGISTRY_NAME }}/test:${{ env.IMAGE_TAG }}
                options: -v ${{ github.workspace }}:/your_dockerfile_workdir

                registry: ${{ env.REGISTRY_NAME }}
                username: ${{ env.REGISTRY_USERNAME }}
                password: ${{ env.REGISTRY_PASSWORD }}
                run: pytest
```

For some reason, in this action the `with.image` does accept variables

Answer (score 1):

Why not do it as

```
container:
  image: ghcr.io/${{ github.repository_owner }}/test:${{ github.sha }}
```

and basically cut out the env middle man since the `env` context is not available?  If you are using the value many times, I understand the desire to avoid repetition and define it in one place, but in your specific example those env vars are only used twice, so it may be an acceptable workaround to the fact that `env` context is not available for container (at last as of this date...I suspect at some future point GitHub will change it).