# GitHub action - how to parameterize container image hostname

Tags: workflow, github-actions, jobs

I have a GitHub action with a workflow that uses a container to run it, using a private docker registry (myhostname.com - see below).

```
jobs:
  myjob:
    name: My Job
    runs-on: [ some-tag-on-runners ]
    container:
      image: myhostname.com/dir/subdir/image:latest
```

I tried parameterizing `myhostname.com` using the {{ $secrets.SOME_SECRET }} feature but it doesn't work. I need to have this workflow in several repos and if the hostname changes I would like to be able to change it in only one place. Can't seem to find anything in the docs at GitHub.

Comment: all ${{}} variables doesn't work in definitions I am afraid - I have similar problem with dynamic versioning across different workflows

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski: so I understand you've hit this problem, tried the same and found no solution so far?

Comment: unfortunately, I asked on community channel for github and noone pointed me to any available solution as of today

Comment: [Some context variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76432348/1048572) appear to work in `jobs.*.container.image`

Comment: Did you mean `${{ secrets.SOME_SECRET }}` instead of `{{ $secrets.SOME_SECRET }}`?