# Github Action needs context is not available in container.image

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm trying to parametrize the `jobs.myjob.container.image` field. The documentation says the `needs` context is available there:

[Contexts documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#context-availability)

Specifically this:

| Workflow key | Context |
| --- | --- |
| jobs.<job_id>.container | github, needs, strategy, matrix, env, secrets, inputs |

But it doesn't work. My job output is an empty string, causing an error.

```
  get_image:
    name: get_image
    runs-on: self-hosted
    outputs:
      image: ${{ steps.jq.image }}
    needs:
      - ...
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: jq
        id: jq
        run: |
          set -x
          export TAG=$(jq -r '.${{ github.event.inputs.cluster }} | .tag' data.json)
          echo "::set-output name=image::registry.com/mycontainer:$TAG"

  job2:
    name: job2
    runs-on: self-hosted
    needs:
      - get_image
    container:
      image: ${{ needs.get_image.outputs.image }} <--- this is an empty string
      credentials:
        ...
    steps:
        ...
```

The error I'm getting is `Error: The template is not valid. ...: Unexpected value ''`.

**Is the documentation lying to me or am I just reading it wrong?**

Other questions lead me to think that the thing I want to do is not allowed.

- [parametrize container.image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71301320/github-action-how-to-parameterize-container-image-hostname)
- [github community discussion](https://github.com/community/community/discussions/26324)

Comment: Please re-run with debug and show the logs how the output is set in the first job

Comment: Thanks @rethab, looks like we have an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `outputs` here `image: ${{ steps.jq.outputs.image }}`.

Comment: It works!! Thank you! So many hours yesterday banging my head against the wall. At least it wasn't a semicolon.