# Using a dynamic tag in github actions workflow

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, github-actions

I've setup a CI flow on github actions that creates a docker container in the first job.
This container image is used for later jobs, so that all building of dependencies and testing happens in the same environment.

```yaml
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  REGISTRY: ghcr.io
  IMAGE_NAME: ${{ github.repository }}

jobs:
  build-container:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container: docker:20.10.24-git
    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: True
      - name: Log in to Container registry
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          registry: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
          username: ${{ github.actor }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      - name: Extract metadata (tags, labels) for Docker
        id: meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@v4
        with:
          images: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}/${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}
      - name: Build and push Docker image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
        with:
          context: .
          file: diana/docker/Dockerfile.tvm
          push: true
          labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}
          tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
    outputs:
      container_tag: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
  
  build-htvm-release:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
      image: 'ghcr.io/kuleuven-micas/htvm:main'
    needs: build-container
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: True
      - name: Build HTVM Release
        run: |
          mkdir build
          cp diana/config.cmake build
          cd build
          cmake ..
          make -j$(nproc)
          cd ..
      - name: Store HTVM Build
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: build
          path: build
```

This flow works, however it fails when a person makes a PR that creates a change to the docker image.

This is because the the first job will push a new image to the registry (e.g. `ghcr.io/htvm:pr-7`), but the later jobs always use the `main` tag, so only after the PR is accepted the CI can actually pass, which is obviously not ideal.

I've tried to change `build-htvm-release.container.image` line from `ghcr.io/kuleuven-micas/htvm:main` to `'ghcr.io/kuleuven-micas/htvm:${{ needs.build_container.outputs.container_tag}}'`
But this constantly seems to fail.
It appears that github actions does not like me to put a variable in that `image` line.
So now the CI just fails because `ghcr.io/kuleuven-micas/htvm:` is not a valid image reference.

Does anyone have any suggestions to make this possible with minimal adaptation of the current flow?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I found out that I had already asked myself this question before and found an answer to the question and posted it here:
[Github Actions dynamic container name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324777/github-actions-dynamic-container-name/76012636#76012636)

This question is about using a dynamic name, but the solution can also be used for dynamic tags.

If someone could mark this as a duplicate that would be great, thanks!